# Turning a select statement with group and having clause into a delete?

Tags: sql, duplicates, sybase, sql-delete

I have an issue with duplicates. This query selects the duplicates

```sql
select account_number, acc_cd, seq, count (*)
FROM table
group by account_number, acc_cd, seq
having count(*)>1
```

Now I want to turn that into a delete statement to remove the results of the select statement?

I have already moved 1 copy of the duplicate into a tmp table so I can delete all the data from the select?

Does anyone know how to do it? I've seen nested queries but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
delete from MyTable
where exists (
    select 1 from MyTable t2
    where MyTable.account_number=t2.account_number and MyTable.acc_cd=t2.acc_cd and MyTable.seq=t2.seq
)
```

Comment: Hi, cheers, when i try running that in sybase im getting the error, "subquery only allowed one select list item" i thought the issue was with count (*) but it still happens?

Comment: Hi, thanks for that but it doesnt like more than one value in the WHERE IN claus.
I am just going to move to tmp table then delete where excists